# What is the difference between data-dojo-type and dojotype?

Tags: dojo

There are two kind of **type declaration** mentioned in dojo documentation. They are `data-dojo-type` and `dojotype`.

For example,

```
dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid"

data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid"
```

Both are working fine in all major browser.But i don't understand, *What is the difference between  data-dojo-type and dojotype?*

Where should i use `dojoType`? and where should i use `data-dojo-type`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think its a new syntax of the same thing, maybe its functionality is slightly different as it is adjusted for html5, you can read more [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/html5data-attributes). Anyway from what i saw its recommended to use data-dojo-type...

Answer (score 3):

From dojo 1.6 documentation:

The dojoType attribute has been deprecated, and will be unsupported in 2.0. Replace all occurrences of dojoType with data-dojo-type, as the behavior is mostly identical, with the following caveats:

> when using data-dojo-type, all widget properties must be stashed on a
>   single attribute: data-dojo-props

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/1.6.html

Comment: I believe putting all properties into data-dojo-props was in release 1.6 only.  It had a large community backlash and was dropped in 1.7.  See [link](http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2011/05/dojo-1-6-parser-confusion/)